# Cypress: How to check if the element has a text but the text is not specific?

Tags: cypress

Is there any other ways to check if an element has text?

```
cy.get('h1').should('have.text','Enter your text')
```

I have this code but i don't want the text to be exact what i want to check. I just want to check if the element has text on it or not.

Comment: So you want to validate part of the text and not the entire text ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Another way, test for any text of non-zero length

```js
cy.visit('http://example.com')
cy.get('h1').invoke('text').should('have.length.gt', 0)  // gt == greater than
cy.get('h1').invoke('text').should('not.be.empty')       // not.be.empty == NOT "" 
cy.get('h1').should('not.have.text', "")                 // also NOT ""
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to validate partial text, you can:

```js
cy.get('h1').should('include.text','partial text')
```

If you just want to check whether your element has some inner text irrespective of whatever it is you can:

```js
cy.get('h1').invoke('text').should('have.length', 1)
```

As @kame suggested you can also add an assertion as the length is greater than 0, in case the above doesn't work.

```js
cy.get('h1').invoke('text').should('have.length.gt', 0)
```

Comment: `cy.get('h1').invoke('text').should('have.length.gt', 0)` should be correct, no?

Comment: Ya that is true as well. Depends what on we get from `invoke(text)`. I will also add this in the answer. Thanks for the suggestion @kame

Comment: I would not use `.should('have.length', 1)`. @Kame's correction is better.

Answer (score 0):

This is how one can validate part of the text and not the entire text:

```
 cy.visit('http://example.com')
 cy.get('h1').should('have.length.greaterThan', 0)  //greater than     
 cy.get('h1').should('not.be.empty')   // not.be.empty == NOT "" 
 cy.get('h1').should('contain.text', 'partial text of full text') // contains 
                                                   partial text of the full text"
```